# Drupal 8 theme showing Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).once is not a function in console

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I've created a demo theme. The `.libraries.yml` file is below:

```
global-styling-and-scripts:
 version: VERSION
 css:
  base:
   assets/css/font-awesome.css: {}
   assets/css/bootstrap.css: {}
   assets/css/slick.css: {}
   assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css: {}
   assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css: {}
   assets/css/theme-color/default-theme.css: {}
   assets/css/style.css: {}
  theme:
   '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine': { type: external, minified: true }
   '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans': { type: external, minified: true }
   '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prata': { type: external, minified: true }
 js:
  assets/js/jquery.min.js: {}
  assets/js/bootstrap.js: {}
  assets/js/slick.js: {}
  assets/js/waypoints.js: {}
  assets/js/jquery.counterup.js: {}
  assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js: {}
  assets/js/jquery.mixitup.js: {}
  assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js: {}
  assets/js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
   - core/drupalSettings
   - core/jquery
   - core/jquery.once
```

If I deleted all the `.js` from this file, I see no errors in the console however, the images, and slideshows etc are not properly rendering.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to see, but check that your `dependencies` key in the YAML is indented correctly. It should be on the top level, and in your code it looks like it's inside the `js` key. This could cause it to not load the dependencies, which include the jquery.once module.

(I suggest using two spaces instead of one for indenting YAML, which is consistent with Drupal's standard and makes the indentation more visible.)

Edit: Also, note that there is a dedicated Drupal Stackexchange site at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/, where your Drupal-related questions can get more visibility.